# Python grouped backreferences

Tags: python, html, regex, html-parsing

I am cleaning the output of some `html` that probably originated with a WYSIWYG. There are a bunch of empty formatting tags that I'd like to get rid of for sanity's sake.

e.g.

```html
<em></em> Here's some text <strong>   </strong> and here's more <em> <span></span></em>
```

Thanks to [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html), I have a neat regex with a backreference to unwrap one layer at a time

```
# Returns a string minus one level of empty formatting tags
def remove_empty_html_tags(input_string):
    return re.sub(r'<(?P<tag>strong|span|em)\b[^>]*>(\s*)</(?P=tag)>', r'\1', input_string)
```

However, I'd like to be able to unwrap all the layers at once for the `<em> <span></span></em>`, and there are potentially 5+ layers of nested empty tags.

Is there a way to group a backref a la `(?:<?P<tagBackRef>strong|span|em)\b[^>]>(\s)*)+` (or something) and use it later with `(</(?P=tagBackRef>)+` to delete multiple nested but matching empty `html` tags?

#### For posterity:

This was probably an [XY Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/230855), wherein the tool I hoped to use for the outcome I wanted is not the one anyone else would have chosen. [Henry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18883272/241211) answered the question, but he and everyone else will point you to an html parser over a regex for parsing html. =)

Comment: This is why people tell you not to use regular expressions to parse HTML. Use a HTML parser instead.

Comment: you need an hard upper bound on layers of nesting ... and the regex gets alot longer (and more complicated) with each potential layer

Comment: @MartijnPieters and what, walk the tree looking for `re.match('^\s*$', innerText)`?

Comment: @Michael: That'd work, with BeautifulSoup at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *really* don't want to use an [HTML parser](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), and you're not overly concerned with speed (which I assume you're not, or you wouldn't be using regexes to clean your HTML) you can just modify the code you already wrote. Just put your replacement in a loop (or recursion; your preference) and return when you don't change anything.

```
# Returns a string minus all levels of empty formatting tags
def remove_empty_html_tags(input_string):
    matcher = r'<(?P<tag>strong|span|em)\b[^>]*>(\s*)</(?P=tag)>'
    old_string = input_string
    new_string = re.sub(matcher, r'\1', old_string)
    while new_string != old_string:
        old_string = new_string
        new_string = re.sub(matcher, r'\1', new_string)
    return new_string
```

Answer (score 4):

This is much easier to do with an HTML parser, like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), for example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup("""
<body>
    <em></em> Here's some <span><strong>text</strong></span> <strong>   </strong> and here's more <em> <span></span></em>
</body>
""")

for element in soup.findAll(name=['strong', 'span', 'em']):
    if element.find(True) is None and (not element.string or not element.string.strip()):
        element.extract()

print soup
```

prints:

```
<html><body>
 Here's some <span><strong>text</strong></span>  and here's more <em> </em>
</body></html>
```

As you can see, all `span`, `strong` and `em` tags with empty (or consisting with whitespaces only) contents were removed.

Also see:

- [Remove/delete/extract empty tags](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/beautifulsoup/yC_IU2PDJgY)

Comment: Be careful, `element.string is None` when there are nested elements; those could have text.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks, I've added `element.find(True) is None` condition, should help.

Comment: Thanks, alecxe. I was hoping, though, that the empty `<em>  </em>` would also have been removed on the first pass.

Comment: @Michael this is because em tag contained a span tag inside. The simplest solution here would be to run the "filter" code several times.